# Where is my boost lib file?

Tags: libraries, paths, boost

I am using boost. I installed it using `sudo apt-get install`. Now I am unable to find my boost lib file on my filesystem.

I want to include the path of the lib in my Qt project. grepping is taking too long :( I found the includes in `/usr/include/boost`. But I also need to know the library path.

Comment: sudo apt-get install... what?

Comment: @EricCarvalho `libboost-dev`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you probably want to install `libboost-all-dev`.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libboost*.so

/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph_parallel-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph_parallel.so
/usr/lib/libboost_graph.so
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99f.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99l.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_c99.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1f.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1l.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_math_tr1.so
/usr/lib/libboost_mpi-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_mpi.so
/usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so
/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py27.so
/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py32.so
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py32.so
/usr/lib/libboost_python.so
/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so
/usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so
/usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_signals.so
/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
/usr/lib/libboost_wave-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_wave.so
/usr/lib/libboost_wserialization-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_wserialization.so
```

Answer (score 44):

If you are on a 64bit machine then you will probably
find the files under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52617/what-is-usr-lib-i386-linux-gnu-for) for an explanation of what this folder is for.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the library path for `boost` was in `/usr/lib64`, and that's all I had to add to my library path for the code to build properly. On a different machine, I found it installed under `/usr/lib`.

If `locate` is available to you on your system, then try these for locating `boost`:

```
locate boost | fgrep .so   #find lib files      (/usr/lib64 for me)
locate boost | fgrep .hpp  #find include files  (/usr/include for me)
```

Answer (score 1):

libboost-dev depends on libboost1.46-dev (Ubuntu 12.04) or libboost1.49-dev (Ubuntu 12.10). Both packages also install a lot of files in `/usr/share/boost-build/`. Maybe it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To list all installed files for a package and the dependencies, use `debfoster`

```
sudo apt-get install debfoster
```

and a script like this. In this example I have used the package `libboost-all-dev`

```
debfoster -d libboost-all-dev |\
    awk '! /depends on/ {\
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {\
            printf "\n>>> %s \n",$i; system("dpkg -L "$i)\
        }\
    }'
```

To list only the `*.so` files

```
debfoster -d  libboost-all-dev |\
    awk '! /depends on/ {\
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {\
            printf "\n>>> %s \n",$i; system("dpkg -L "$i" | grep -P \".so($|\.)\"")\
        }\
    }'
```