# what is the difference between different 'lib' folder in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

In the root directory, we can find several 'lib' subfolder, for example, `/lib`, `lib32`, `lib64`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib32`, `/usr/local/lib`.

What are their differences?

Comment: If that question is not specific enough for you, edit this one with any particular questions you have and we'll vote to re-open it.

Comment: @Flimm Agreed. The below answer was provided during/while I was looking at the new edits in the other question and seems to be more detailed.

Comment: @Flimm FWIW, I like the fact that this question is focused just on the `lib` directories, and I think it's useful on its own. Also this question isn't specific to 12.04, there might be a better tag for this.

Comment: Also related: [What is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/52617/509967)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`/lib` contain "essential" libraries that may be needed even in single-user (admin-only) mode and without `/usr` mounted

`/usr/lib` are the libraries for the normal user-programs, that mostly can be found under `/usr`.

`/usr/local/lib` are the libraries for locally installed programs and packages ie. things you've compiled and installed from source-packages yourself.

In addition to shared and static libraries which are the lib-directories main purpose, you may also find some hierarchies (with their own lib, bin, include and so on) for some larger packages under them.

`lib32` and `lib64` are used on 64-bits systems to separate libraries for 32-and 64-bits.

Comment: for the specific 'lib' file in '/usr/local/lib', how can I include it in my program ? Thanks

Comment: The command ldconfig updates the system's cache over libraries, so after installing a new library, you should run this. There is also a config-file /etc/ld.so.conf which specify where ldconfig will look for new libraries, and you can add unusual library-location - like libraries with the actual lib-files in their own subdirs.  /usr/local/lib should already be there, so if your library was installed directly under /usr/local/lib, running ldconfig should be enough.  More in part #2

Comment: Now the system knows where the library is, but often you need to specify unusual libraries to the gcc and g++ compilers and linker as well.  In your program you use #include to specify the library's header file.  To compile:  "gcc -Wall -I/path/to/includefile -c myprogram.c" Here it's probably /usr/local/include, which should be found anyway.  To link with the library, you would use the command "gcc -L/path/to/library -lnameoflibrary -lotherlibraries myprogram.o"  Again, /usr/local/lib should be found automatically, but if the lib was in a subdir, you surely would need to specify.