# another /lib question: domain wide lib folder

Tags: libraries, shared-library

my intention here is not to create another duplicate thread similar to [what is the difference between different 'lib' folder in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281660/what-is-the-difference-between-different-lib-folder-in-ubuntu)

I have a cluster of machines, all running either Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 (we have potentially up to 2 versions during transition periods).
I need to run the same program on all machines, and this program is dependent on a *.so file that comes with Ubuntu in /usr/lib/ folder. However it turns out that different machines have different versions of this *.so file, which creates issues.

My question is the following: Is it possible (and recommended) to create a library folder shared by all machines of the domain, for instance we could mount at startup, that contains one version of this file, and that would have priority over the other local lib folders (to ensure that this shared version is always selected)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that. You're much better off looking into config management like Puppet or Chef (or any of the others, whichever suits you best) to manage it best. You can then pin certain packages pretty easily to versions and ensure that all machines are running all the same packages etc.

You should be able to get yourself in a position where all the 12.04 servers have the same version and all the 14.04 servers have the same version fairly easily also through regular updates. You may need to (carefully) apt-get dist-upgrade some of the machines to get to the same point release. Some may be 14.04.3 others may be 14.04.4. If they are all up to date and the same release version you shouldn't see much variance in package versions at all.